# AppEngine python's send_email not working anymore

Tags: google-app-engine

My appengine app has a cron job that calls a url endpoint whose handler uses mail.send_mail from google.appengine.api. This has been working fine for several months so far.

Today, the email never arrived. I wrote some test code to invoke send_mail, but the email does not get sent. I have adhered to the necesarry requirements like sending from a email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com.

The function is not throwing any exception either. The appengine logs note that the url is invoked, but there is no error or exception.

What might be the problem? Thanks.

Editing to add some code as suggested. Note that to actually test this code one'd need an AppEngine App. In that case you'd need to change myApp etc. in the code below to the actual app name that is used.

Looking forward to any help/insights.

```
from google.appengine.api import mail

class TestEmailHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def get(self):                  
        mySender = "mySender <mySender@myApp.appspotmail.com>"
        myTo = "myToAddress@example.com"
        mySubject = "Test Subject"
        myBody = "Test Body Text"
        myHtml = "<html><body>Test body</body></html>"
        try:
            mail.send_mail(sender=mySender,
                           to=myTo,
                           subject=mySubject,
                           body=myBody,
                           html=myHtml)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.write("Sent email. Body: " + myBody)        
        except:
            self.response.write("Exception. " + sys.exc_info()[0])

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/test_email', TestEmailHandler)
], debug=True)
```

My app.yaml looks like this:

```
application: myApp
version: 2
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: myApp.application

inbound_services:
- mail
```

Comment: Please add source code, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Edited the question to include code. Thanks.

Comment: Weird, just tested exact code also from a cron and email was sent. What's in your config, your `app.yaml`?

Comment: Very strange. Updated the question with my app.yaml as well. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem's now fixed. I associated my credit card by enabling billing and now an email got sent when I tested it. Who would've thought...